# Is it possible to invert Jquery selectors to include everything except this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Jquery if you want to select something you can use various combinations of selector. Is is possible to invert this selection?

```
var item = $('#someitemparent').html($('#someitem'));
```

Is it possible to invert this to everything thing else but not `#someitem`?

```
<div id='#someitemparent'>
<div id='#someitem'>
....
</div>
... otheritems
</div>
```

Comment: Of course. There are several ways to do this. Why do you need every element on the page except one?

Comment: I wanted to clear contents of everything else after a Ajax call.

Comment: it depends on what you want to do.... if it is an event handler and you want to ignore events from `someitem` and it is bubbling event then you may have to use a different logic

Comment: So why not select the element, clear the content, and then re-append the element?

Comment: "I wanted to clear contents of everything else" Well this would include #someitem parents, as body

Comment: looks like you need some combination of .not() as below, and .empty().  Doing .empty() for everything except the item below would accomplish what you're trying to do I think? http://api.jquery.com/empty/.  Of course, there are things to consider (as @A.Wolff points out) such as clearing unwanted objects...  maybe sending the value of an answer of #someitem as a request parameter or attribute would be more desirable.

Comment: @A.Wolff Well #someitem is a orphan he dosen't have any parents :P

Comment: @FloodGravemind it still has body has parent

Comment: If `#someitem` is an orphan, then why do you need to filter it out of a selection?

Comment: @A.Wolff and cookiemonster I don't know why you marked the question negative after I declared my purpose. My purpose has nothing to do with the question. How I use the code is my problem.

Comment: @FloodGravemind i don't know how you know downvoters... My point was you need to filter parents too. Better would be you set class for all elements to cancel and use that class as selector instead

Comment: then: `$('#someitemparent').children(':not(#someitem)').empty()`

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks sorry abt that thing.

Comment: @FloodGravemind No worry! You could use that too: `$(#someitem).siblings().empty()`

Comment: @FloodGravemind: There are often several ways to accomplish a problem, some better than others. That's why it's more useful to ask about the problem rather than what you assumed is the best solution. When you don't, you get technically correct but horrible solutions like `$(':not(#someitem)');` from people who didn't really care about the answer, but only wanted to be first. While technically correct answer, just a tiny bit of thought would cause a person to realize that it would almost *never* be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) or [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
var item = $('.someitem').not('#notme');
```

---

```
var item = $('*').not('#notme');
```